# Tapestry Zone Render After Validation

Tags: tapestry

I have a Select Enum component within a form that updates a zone when changed. This is working well:

```
<t:select t:id="anEnum" validate="required" zone="${getZone()}" />

public String getZone() {
    if (anEnum== AnEnum.TYPE1) {
        return "zone1";
    } else if (anEnum== AnEnum.TYPE2) {
        return "zone2";
    } else {
        return "zone3";
    }
}

@OnEvent(value = EventConstants.VALUE_CHANGED, component = "anEnum")
public Object updateDisplay(AnEnum anEnumIn) {
    anEnum= anEnumIn;
    if (anEnum== AnEnum.TYPE1) {
        return zone1.getBody();
    } else if (anEnum== AnEnum.TYPE2) {
        return zone2.getBody();
    } else {
        return zone3.getBody();
    }
}
```

The problem I've having is that when I submit a form and the validation is handled in the java class in an onValidate method, the page rerenders with the wrong zone displayed - usually zone 3 (this might make sense as its the 'else' return in the methods above). How do I get the correct zone to render again - I've tried  @persist on the anEnum with no luck  and the following didnt work either

```
@SetupRender
void setupRender() {
  updateDisplay(anEnum);
}
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You are checking on `anTypeEnum` instance variable in `getZone()`, where you are setting `anEnum` instance variable in `updateDisplay()`. If this is not a typo in your question, there's your problem.

If this is a typo, `anTypeEnum` will be null for some reason. But without your full code I can't comment on how this is happening. It will be cleared between the form submit and page render if you don't `@Persist` it or use an `onPassivate()` and `onActivate()` to persist the value across requests. It should work with `@Persist` so you must be setting it to null one way or the other. Please share your complete component/page code.

PS: in stead of `zone="${getZone()}"` use `zone="zone"`

Comment: Thanks for the response. It was a typo and I've updated the code in the question. I had thought persist would work too. I'll check out the onPassvate and onActivate methods - I'm not using them currently. If I still have an issue in an hour I'll post the full code.

Comment: P.S I can upvote you good sir - my reputation is too low... :(

Comment: Good luck. Do post some code regardless as it will help people with the same problem down the line.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to the issue - might have been found by a community member if I had posted fuller code earlier (lesson learned!).

Following an example I had seen (apologies I've since lost the link) on updating zones using a Select I had set one of my two zones to visible="false".

```
<t:zone t:id="zone1" id="Zone1" visible="false">
```

This meant that even though the page re-rendered after validation the visible= false took precedent. I've updated the code to call a method in the java to check to whether the zone is visible.

tml

```
<t:zone t:id="zone1" id="Zone1" visible="${isZoneVisible()}">
```

java

```
public boolean isZoneVisible() {
    if (anEnum== AnEnum.TYPE1) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Adding a @persist to the anEnum as suggested by joostschouten was also a good idea.

Happy to say it's all working as expected now.

Comment: Instead of visible="${isZoneVisible()}" you should use visible="zoneVisible" or visible="prop:zoneVisible". See [here](http://tapestry.apache.org/component-parameters.html#ComponentParameters-Don%27tusethe%24%5Csyntax%5C%21)

Comment: I tried it after joostschouten suggested it and didn't like it. In all honesty I'm not a fan of Tapestry. I find the documentation lacking and the implementation clumsy. I'm happier the solution I've implemented for a number of reasons (including clarity and issues on re-render). Thanks for the input however.

Comment: I hope you realise that ```foo="${foo}"``` is a one-way binding (get only) and that ```foo="prop:foo"``` is a two-way binding (allowing get and set). ```${foo}``` also requires a coercion to String whereas ```prop:foo``` does not.